# The boolean fields which are prefixed with "is" are not stored in index after upgrading to spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

After upgrading to the spring-boot-starter:2.2.5.RELEASE, spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR3, spring-cloud-stream-dependencies:Horsham.SR3  & spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.5.RELEASE.  The boolean fields are not stored in index/document.  It was working earlier with spring boot 2.1.11.

I tried to create document manually using the ElasticSearch REST API.  When tried directly with REST API, the boolean fields are stored in index.

Is there any changes done how the mappings are declared for boolean fields?

I'm using the ElasticsearchTemplate.index(IndexQuery) API to create an index document, where the IndexQuery is built with an document object having some boolean fields.

The following are the boolean fields in the CatalogIndex.java file.

```
@Document(indexName = "catalogentity")
public class CatalogIndex {

  private boolean isType;
  private boolean isAbstract;
  private boolean isFinal;
  private String stateId;
  private String stageId;
  //some other fields

  public boolean isType() {
    return isType;
  }

  public void setType(final boolean type) {
    isType = type;
  }

  public boolean isAbstract() {
    return isAbstract;
  }

  public void setAbstract(final boolean anAbstract) {
    isAbstract = anAbstract;
  }

  public boolean isFinal() {
    return isFinal;
  }

  public void setFinal(final boolean aFinal) {
    isFinal = aFinal;
  }

  //some other setter and getters
```

The mappings are as follows

```
{
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "abstract": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "final": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "stateId": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "stageId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Santhosh

Comment: how do you configure spring data elasticsearch? How do you store documents? And what does the index mappings look like in Elasticsearch?

Comment: The elastic search is configured using the TransportClient.  The documents are stored using the ElasticsearchTemplate.index(IndexQuery) API.  Where the Index Query is built with java document object.  Added more details in the above question.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was working earlier.  There is problem withboolean fields prefixed with "is" in java document file.  The indexing is working If I change the fields as isType -> type, isFinal -> final1 and isAbstract -> abstract1 with getter and setters as isType1(), setType1(), isFinal1(), setFinal1(), isAbstract1() and setAbstract1().

Answer (score 0):

The following is the working configuration for boolean fields.  I was not sure why it was working fine before upgrade.

The following are the boolean fields in the CatalogIndex.java file.

```
@Document(indexName = "catalogentity")
public class CatalogIndex {

  private boolean isType;
  private boolean abstract1;
  private boolean final1;
  private String stateId;
  private String stageId;
  //some other fields

  public boolean isType() {
    return isType;
  }

  public void setType(final boolean type) {
    isType = type;
  }

  public boolean isAbstract1() {
    return abstract1;
  }

  public void setAbstract1(final boolean abstract1) {
    this.abstract1 = abstract1;
  }

  public boolean isFinal1() {
    return final1;
  }

  public void setFinal1(final boolean final1) {
    this.final1 = final1;
  }

  //some other setter and getters
```

The mappings are as follows

```
{
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "abstract1": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "final1": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "stateId": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "stageId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```